# How to sort array of object as windows explorer?

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort an arrya of object as windows explorer, I actually tried the following way:

```
$array = [
    ['name' => '861_Villa Foo (1).jpg'],
    ['name' => '861_Villa Hello (11).jpg'],
    ['name' => '861_Villa World (2.1).jpg']
];

usort($array, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});

var_dump($array);
```

current output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "861_Villa Foo (1).jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "861_Villa Hello (11).jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(25) "861_Villa World (2.1).jpg"
  }
}
```

I would like to have the same organization of Windows Explorer, so the wish output should be this:

```
861_Villa Foo (1).jpg, 861_Villa World (2.1).jpg, 861_Villa Hello (11).jpg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you natsort an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835112/how-do-you-natsort-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and `preg_match` to extract the number inside the parentheses and compare the extracted value as floating point numbers when parentheses, with numbers inside them,are present in the filename.Otherwise you can compare normally.

Something like this should work:

```
   <?php

$array = [
    ['name' => '861_Villa Foo (1).jpg'],
    ['name' => '861_Villa Hello (11).jpg'],
    ['name' => '861_Villa World (2.1).jpg']

];

usort($array, function($a, $b)
{
preg_match("/\(([^)]+)\)/",$a['name'],$a_matches);
preg_match("/\(([^)]+)\)/",$b['name'],$b_matches);

$a_match=(float)end($a_matches);
$b_match=(float)end($b_matches);

if($a_match && $b_match){

return $a_match>$b_match;

}else{

return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);

}

});

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I get `Undefined offset: 1` on this line ` if(!empty((float)$a_val[1]) && !empty((float)$b_val[1])){`